# NSURL array parameter in query

Tags: ios, http, nsurl

I need to build a NSURL containing an array in the query segment. Array notation looks like this:

```
test.com?arr[a]=1&arr[b]=2
```

The problem here is that NSURL escapes the brackets so the final query segment looks like this:

```
test.com?arr%5Ba%5D=1&arr%5Bb%5D=2
```

After some research i stumbled upon the NSURLComponents class but just like i already expected, NSURLQueryItem objects can only take NSStrings as value and thus not create the wanted output either. I could not find a way to build a NSURL object containing unescaped brackets yet.

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.com?arr[a]=1&arr[b]=2"]` seems to work just fine

Comment: I don't think so. When i call `[NSURL URLWithString:@"test.com?arr[a]=1&arr[b]=2"]` i get a NSURL object with escaped brackets.

Comment: In my personal opinion that's misuse of the query pattern.

Comment: no, actually it's not. This is the de facto http standard to put (assoc.) arrays in the query part of a get request.

Answer (score 0):

Add the character you want to keep to theSet

```
NSString *myString = @"http://foo.bar/?key[]=value";
NSCharacterSet *theSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~!*():/?[]="];
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[myString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:theSet]];
```

I'm not sure if this work, if I move mouse on `myUrl` to preview it show `[]`
but if I do `po myurl.absoluteString` it show escape

Comment: This is still using `[NSURL URLWithString:]` so it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not relevant anymore. As far as i can say, it is not possible to build NSURL objects containing unescaped brackets. If anyone still finds a way to do this, feel free to leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it hasn't been answered so here goes:

```
NSArray *queryItems = @[
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"arr[a]" value:@"1"],
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"arr[b]" value:@"2"],
];
[components setQueryItems:queryItems];
```